# DocuSign API - Get Account Envelopes Count/Remaining Envelopes

Tags: docusignapi

Is there a DocuSign API endpoint I can call to retrieve the number of remaining envelopes in our account? For example if we are allowed 500 envelopes annually I would like to make an API call to get the number of sent/remaining envelopes for our plan within the current subscription period?

I've looked through the API docs and haven't been able to find an endpoint so far that will return this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This endpoint:
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/accounts/accounts/getbillingcharges/

"allowedQuantity" - total enveloped

"usedQuantity": used so far